# How do I set the default transaction isolation level in Fluent NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I would like to set the default transaction level to ReadCommitted in my Fluent NHibernate configuration. If I were using XML mapping files, I could add a key to my config file:

```
<add key="hibernate.connection.isolation" value="ReadCommitted" />
```

but I can't figure out how to accomplish this with Fluent configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Fluent NHibernate **v 2.x** `IsolationLevel()` method can be used to globally set isolation level for transactions:

```
MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
    .IsolationLevel(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted)
```

Answer (score 6):

> Fluent NHibernate doesn't do anything with the transaction isolation, so the default will be whatever NHibernate defaults to. I don't know off the top of my head what that is.
>
> We don't have an explicit method to set the isolation, but as it's just a configuration value you can use the Raw method to set the property.

```
MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.Raw("connection.isolation", "isolation_level");
```

Source: https://web.archive.org/web/20100812054505/http://support.fluentnhibernate.org/discussions/help/45-default-isolation-level-for-transactions

Comment: I found that too but it's not working for me. It is handling the setting because it throws an exception if I set it to an unsupported IsolationLevel (Chaos). But the profiler still shows the level as Unspecified unless I set it when beginning the transaction.

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe the Unspecified on profiler just means that you didn't set any isolation level to this transaction, so nh will use the default one ?

Comment: The source link is dead

Answer (score 5):

You should specify isolation level, when calling: BeginTransaction on your Session object.

```
...
ISession session = SessionFactory.OpenSession();
session.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
...
```

Please refer to: [NHibernate transactions](http://nhibernate.info/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/09/08/part-9-nhibernate-transactions.aspx) for more details.